# Does parallel_test [cucumber] allows user to run iOS tests on multiple machines in parallel?

Tags: ios, ruby, jruby, frank, parallel-testing

I have my Frank tests for iOS and they are using cucumber. Is it possible for me to use parallel test to distribute the .feature file to multiple machines using parallels and invoke the tests on multiple iOS simulators on different machine. If yes, how do you suggest to do this.

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to do it?